# Extract date and sort rows by date

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataset that includes some strings in the following forms:

```
Text
Jun 28, 2021 — Brendan Moore is p...
Professor of Psychology at University
Aug 24, 2019 — Chemistry (Nobel prize...
by A Craig · 2019 · Cited by 1 — Authors. ...
... 2020 | Volume 8 | Article 330Edited by:
```

I would like to create a new column where there are, if there exist, dates sorted by ascending order.
To do so, I need to extract the part of string which includes date information from each row, whether exits.

Something like this:

```
Text                                                Numbering
    Jun 28, 2021 — Brendan Moore is p...                2
    Professor of Psychology at University               -1
    Aug 24, 2019 — Chemistry (Nobel prize...            1
    by A Craig · 2019 · Cited by 1 — Authors. ...       -1
    ... 2020 | Volume 8 | Article 330Edited by:         -1

All the rows not starting with a date (that follows the format: Jun 28, 2021 — are assigned to -1.
```

- The first step would be identify the pattern: xxx xx, xxxx;
- then, transforming date object into datetime (yyyy-mm-dd).
- Once got this date information, it needs to be converted into numerical, then sorted.

I am having difficulties in answering the last point, specifically on how to filter only dates and sort them in an appropriate way.
The expected output would be

```
Text                                           Numbering (sort by date asc)
Jun 28, 2021 — Brendan Moore is p...                2
Professor of Psychology at University              -1
Aug 24, 2019 — Chemistry (Nobel prize...            1
by A Craig · 2019 · Cited by 1 — Authors. ...       -1 
... 2020 | Volume 8 | Article 330Edited by:         -1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mission accomplished:

```py
# Find rows that start with a date
matches = df['Text'].str.match(r'^\w+ \d+, \d{4}')

# Parse dates out of date rows
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df[matches]['Text'], format='%b %d, %Y', exact=False, errors='coerce')

# Assign numbering for dates
df['Numbering'] = df['date'].sort_values().groupby(np.ones(df.shape[0])).cumcount() + 1

# -1 for the non-dates
df.loc[~matches, 'Numbering'] = -1

# Cleanup
df.drop('date', axis=1, inplace=True)
```

Output:

```
>>> df
                                            Text  Numbering
0           Jun 28, 2021 - Brendan Moore is p...          2
1          Professor of Psychology at University         -1
2       Aug 24, 2019 - Chemistry (Nobel prize...          1
3  by A Craig - 2019 - Cited by 1 - Authors. ...         -1
4    ... 2020 | Volume 8 | Article 330Edited by:         -1
```